# How do I take crash log on Blackberry touch device?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

In one of the site its written that to take a crash log on Blackberry device, on home page we need to press Alt+lglg. This worked fine for me. But on touch devices keyboard does not comes on Home screen, so how do I take  crash log?

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold ?123 to lock the numeric keyboard.  Then press ,5,5.